# Koa cannot get the value of the property inside ctx.request-body

Tags: node.js

Koa cannot get the value of the property inside ctx.request-body

Project koa is generated by koa-generator

Routing section related code
Either require('koa-body') or require('koa-bodyparser')

```
  console.log("ctx")
  console.log(ctx.request.body)
  console.log(ctx.request.body.type)
})
```

The three console.log prints are

```
ctx

{
account:'root',
password: 'test',
type:0
}

undefined
```

I can get the object inside the `ctx.requisition.body` and print it out, but `ctx.request.body.type` is undefined
How to get 'ctx.requisition.body.account'  or 'ctx.requisition.body.password' ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you do this

```
const myObj = JSON.parse(ctx.request.body)
console.log(myObj.type)
```

You'll get ctx.request.body.type